# Service which is also a user-provided service?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, pipeline

I have a Java service to deploy to Bluemix which is a basic-auth protected REST service. The username and password is required in configuration.

I have other Java services that are also deployed to Bluemix which I would like to use this (so the url/username/password is required)

I'd like to only have one place where the username and password is maintained. I am able to create a user-provided service which contains the username and password, and bind that to both the service and the client-service, but this seems messy.

In addition to that, I would have to manually maintain the URL of the service, given that this is "provided" to me by Bluemix, I think it's a bit silly.

Is there a way I can specify to push an app to Bluemix, so it is also available as a service to bind?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You should as part of your continuous integration pipeline add the definition of the user provided service after push command. BTW, you can specify in push command the hostname and domain so the URL won't change.

Comment: If you want a place to store your password/key, you can look into using the [Key Protect](https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/catalog/services/key-protect/) service. I've not used it, but based on the documentation, it allows you to retrieve keys programmaticly. Note that it's only available in the UK region at this time.

Comment: Re: your question about creating your own service. It is possible, but it requires some effort. [This Cloud Foundry documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/overview.html) explains. Basically, you need to have a service broker endpoint in your app that CF will talk to.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking how to create your own (Third party) service on Bluemix. A good starting point could be [Extend your reach: offer your cloud services in the IBM marketplace](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/solutions/partner-landing). Please note that service is not automatically accepted. It needs to fill basic quality, security and legal requirements.